# To count rows that is NOT NULL in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, count, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to number some base rows in table without mixing the ordering. I have table like this:

**Status  ProductId**

```
A       12         
NULL    25
B       35
C       56
NULL    89
NULL    99
D       120
E       140
```

I want to add **No** column, to count Statuses which is not null with same `ProductId` ordering, but, don't want to count `NULL` rows. I want the result like this:

```
  No      Status  ProductId    
  1       A       12         
          NULL    25
  2       B       35
  3       C       56
          NULL    89
          NULL    99
  4       D       120
  5       E       140
```

I work on SQL Sever 2008, SSRS. Someone can give solution in SQL side or in RDL file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
WITH CTE 
AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Status) AS No,
    Status, ProductId
  FROM table1
  WHERE Status IS NOT NULL
) 
SELECT 
  c.No,
  t.Status,
  t.ProductId
FROM  table1 AS t
LEFT JOIN CTE AS c ON c.ProductId = t.ProductId
ORDER BY ProductId;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28cce/4)

You can use this query directly in your report.